# $n$-th roots in a group

Tags: group-theory, examples-counterexamples, exponentiation, radicals

**Background:** I am trying to define rational powers of elements in an arbitrary group. For this, I first define $n$-th powers for $n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$: I call $y$ an $n$-th root of $x$ iff $y^n = x$.

Now, while trying to come up with a definition for rational exponentiation, and then then trying to deduct the various laws of exponents, I am stuck on the following **problem**:

> Let $G$ be a group and $x, y\in G$. Let $m, n\in\mathbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ such that $\gcd(m, n) = 1$ and $x^m = y^n$. Do $x$ and $y$ respectively have $n$-th and $m$-th roots?

I don't think it should be true in general, but my knowledge of groups is limited. Can you give some counterexample?

Any insights in special cases (for instance, take $G$ to be abelian and/or ordered) will be appreciated a lot too!

Comment: Do you mean to define a unary squareroot, for example? That may not be possible if there isn't a way to select one of two solutions to $x^2=a$ in a given group.

Comment: @coffeemath No, I am allowing for multiple square roots.

Answer (score 5):

A counterexample is $G = {\rm SL}(2,3)$ with
$$x = \left(\begin{array}{rr}0&-1\\1&0\end{array}\right)  \quad {\rm and}\quad 
y = \left(\begin{array}{rr}-1&1\\0&-1\end{array}\right).$$
We have $x^2 = y^3 = -I_2$.

Then $x$ does have a cube root because its order is $4$, which is coprime to $3$, but $y$ has no square root, because a square root of $y$ would have order $12$ and there is no such element in $G$. (Note that $G/Z(G) \cong {\rm PSL}(2,3) \cong A_4$ which has no element of order $6$.)

Comment: I am sure that this answers my question. :-)

 However, I am not yet versed with these things, and hence will leave not yet accept the answer.